# how to make two conv nets from a single class and do weight sharing[Siamese net]

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a siamese network , similar to below image 
for representation.

[image]

In this I have made a class SiameseNet which implements one cnn's output. What I am trying to do is that I create two instance of this class to make two different neural nets, with compulsory condition that they both have same weights.THis is what I have tried so far , but haven't reached a working solution due to some mis conceptions regarding how should I vary the scopes and still manage weight sharing or whatever I am missing here.

```
class SiameseNet():
    def __init__(self,X):
        self.input_layer=X
    def model(self):
        with tf.variable_scope('layer1',reuse=True):
            layer1=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.input_layer,filters=8,kernel_size=[1,1],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
            batch_layer1=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=layer1,axis=-1)
            dropout_layer1=tf.layers.dropout(inputs=batch_layer1,rate=0.2)#,training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
        with tf.variable_scope('layer2',reuse=True):
            layer2=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=dropout_layer1,filters=8,kernel_size=[4,4],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
            batch_layer2=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=layer2,axis=-1)
            dropout_layer2=tf.layers.dropout(inputs=batch_layer2,rate=0.2)#,training=mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
        with tf.variable_scope('layer3',reuse=True):
            layer3=tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=dropout_layer2,filters=16,kernel_size=[4,4],padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
            batch_layer3=tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=layer3,axis=-1)
            dropout_layer3=tf.layers.dropout(inputs=batch_layer3,rate=0.2)#,training=mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
        with tf.variable_scope('logits',reuse=True):
            flatten_layer3= tf.layers.flatten(dropout_layer3)
            dense_layer4=tf.layers.dense(inputs=flatten_layer3,units=1000,activation=tf.nn.relu)
            logits=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense_layer4,units=500)
        return logits
```

How i was intending to use it , to make two covnets with shared weights but both receiving different images as input

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    net1=SiameseNet(x1).model() #x1 = Image1
    net2=SiameseNet(x3).model() #x2= Image2
    loss=Loss(2)    
    optimiser=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
    for i in range(4):
        l=sess.run(loss.contrastive_loss(1,net1,net2))
        print(l)
```

This gives me this error

> ValueError: Variable layer1/conv2d/kernel does not exist, or was not
>   created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

What I seeking is any clearance on where I am going wrong in terms of correct usage of tensorflow to make two neural nets from a single class SiameseNet. Any clearance on how to use variable scope here so that I can use same weights .Also, what if I don't use variable scope , would that mean that there will be some duplication of inputs or what.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

- When you set the `reuse` argument of [tf.variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) to `True`, TensorFlow expects the variables (with the name that you provide) to exist within the scope, and that is not the case when you define your first network. Instead you could set `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE`, and the variables will be created in case they don't exist.
- If you don't use variable scope, two different networks with non-shared weights will be created. In case you want to avoid using a variable scope directly, there is also the option of setting `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` in [tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) and [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d).